# Find (a, b, c) which minimizes $\max(a, b, c) - min(a, b, c)$ is infeasible?

Tags: optimization

Is the following objective infeasible ?

$min: f(a, b, c) = \max(a, b, c) - \min(a, b, c)$

In case of fixing the RHS, function could be minimzed by maximizing the LHS.

I have reformlated the problem,

$max: f(a, b, c) = \min(a, b, c)$

$s.t \ \ \ g(a, b, c) = max(a, b, c), \ $  $is \ minimum$

In many cases, I can't take a step through maximizing $f$ without violating $g$.

---

I guess there's something wrong with my assumptions, if so what it is?

Comment: I am not sure if I get what you mean. Isn’t $a=b=c$ minimize that function?

Comment: @Rezha Adrian Tanuharja, No they have to be different, say a set of numbers, they should have a different indices.

Comment: what is your domain?

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh, All real numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearly, the objective function is nonnegative.

Since you impose the constraint that the $3$ inputs are distinct, they must be positive.

Let $c=0, b = \frac{\epsilon}2, a = \epsilon$ where $\epsilon > 0$, we can see that the problem doesn't have a minimum as $\epsilon$ can be made arbitrarily small.